# need duplicates with the merged header column

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge, duplicate

i need urgent help in terms of data duplication. given the data below, i want first sequence to be repeated twice. in short i want 2nd and 3rd column to merge along with the first column. it doesnt coincides. do i need to do it manually all along.

Need help!

```
bta-mir-225            bta-mir-225         ATCG

                       bta-mir-454         TGTCG

bta-mir-454            bta-mir-367        AAAGTA

bta-mir-367
```

All i want is to duplicate 225's sequence in next row along.coinciding the merged matches. i.e.

```
bta-mir-225            bta-mir-225         ATCG

                       **bta-mir-225         ATCG**

bta-mir-454           bta-mir-454         TGTCG

bta-mir-367           bta-mir-367        AAAGTA
```

Comment: It will be helpful to see what you've tried so we don't start suggesting things you've already done. I also have no idea what your trying to do, can you add 2 screen shots, of a before and after to show what you want?

Comment: I understood what qurat is trying to do, but frankly, there is no good way to describe this succintly. Basically, he's using Excel as a relational database. Imagine that he has a relational database with two tables, t1 and t2, with IDs like "bta-mir-225". He's trying to do an outer join of the two tables. But his data is not in a relational database, the contents of the two tables are pasted in an Excel sheet with their columns side by side.

Comment: This isn't clear at all what you need. I can think of many ways to trivially accomplish what I _think_ you are asking, but right now, with only this sample data and no explanation as to what you are trying, it's not enough information to actually know what you want.

Answer (score 3):

This is what databases are designed for, by the way. I suggest you use them instead. However, you are lucky. A simple solution in Excel:

Copy your first column to a new worksheet. On that worksheet add a second column, with the formula in cell B1 of:

```
=LOOKUP("dummy input",A$1:A1)
```

The "dummy input" search is a way to find the next non-blank cell in the source datarange. Then, in C1 of the same sheet, add:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet1!B:C,2,FALSE)
```

where `Sheet1!B:C` refers to your second and third columns of the original data.

Drag these down through your entire dataset.

Comment: Nice! I was certainly thinking too much "inside the box" (or rather inside the single sheet) when I proclaimed it impossible.

Answer (score -2):

*Update* Another answer has proven me wrong. If we understood what the question is about, then there is quite a simple formula to do it.

---

There is no way to do this with a formula. A formula can only manipulate the content of the cell in which it is written. Here, a calculation in one cell can necessitate the shifting of all the cells below it by one, which doesn't work.

If you need to automate it, you need to program a macro in VBA to do it. It isn't a difficult macro to do, but even somebody experienced with that kind of programming will need half an hour. If you are not a programmer, you might need days to learn it.

Assuming you never programmed VBA: If you have several hundred rows, I suggest doing it by hand. For more than a thousand, if you can find someone who can program VBA, get them to do this for you. Alternatively, find somebody who is good with Linq and get them to do it for you in Linqpad. If you can't find such a person, and you are a biologist, not a programmer, it will only be worth learning VBA if you have tens of thousands of rows, else doing it by hand will be more tedious, but might take less time and effort.

Another easy way to do this is to get your data into a database, even a lightweight one as Access. Then do what you want (it's a single operation called an outer join, and with Access, you should be able to copy-paste your data if it's clean enough) and export back to Excel. The same cost/benefit calculation applies: if you know somebody who knows SQL well, 1000+ rows are worth seeking him out. If you would need to learn relational database modelling yourself, and are not talented in learning computer science, you'll need dozens of hours until you're good enough not only to understand what to do, but also to be sure what you did was correct.

Comment: This post doesn't answer the question. I understand that it's length doesn't allow you to post it as a comment, however I think it still would be better to post a very brief comment, than writing an answer not solving the problem.

Comment: @MátéJuhász in all my experience on SE sites, saying "what you are trying to do is impossible" is considered an answer. Writing suggestions what to do instead doesn't make it any less of an answer.

Comment: having multiple different number in one excel cell in number format is impossible, doing this task isn't it. Even with some very complex formula it would be possible without VBA, but also you offer VBA as alternative; question isn't asking for a solution with only formula. I agree, that not possible is a valid answer, however I don't think this would be the case now.

Comment: @MátéJuhász my answer is "it is impossible". If it is incorrect, this is still not a "not an answer", it is a real, but incorrect, answer. Separately from that, I'm still convinced that doing it with a formula is impossible, as the formula in each cell would need to change the contents of all cells below it.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this with formulas. The problem is we don't know _what_  the full scope of "this" the OP wants to do is, not that they cannot do it with formulas.